Does using multiple batteries in series or parallel affect mAh?
Say I have four 3.7V batteries rated at 2700mAh. If I connect the batteries in parallel, will I get 10800mAh or 10.8Ah, or something else? If it is 10.8Ah, how do I know it is (is there a formula for this?) What would it be if connecting them in series?

When connecting cells in parallel, the mAh rating is the sum of each cell's rating.
Rationale: with N cells in parallel, each will take 1/N share of current. So at the same total current, N cells will last N times longer than 1 cell.
When connecting batteries in series, the mAh rating is the rating of the smallest cell.
Rationale: in series, the same current goes through all the cells, they don't share current, instead each cell provides a slice of the whole pack voltage. So if the pack outputs X mA for 1 hour, then each cell also outputs X mA for 1 hour.
In both cases, the total stored energy (in Wh) is the sum of stored energy in all cells. The parallel pack delivers a higher current at a lower voltage, and the series pack delivers a lower current at a higher voltage. Since P=VI, maximum power is the same, and stored energy is also the same in series or parallel.
Which one to use depends on the load's voltage and power requirements. At high power, when low voltage would require ridiculously high current, you'll find series packs. Series is more complicated because it requires balancing the cells when charging and monitoring each for over-charge and over-discharge, and you can't charge it directly from USB. At low power, it is often simpler to use a parallel pack to get the desired capacity, then a DC-DC converter to get the desired voltage.
If your pack has 10Ah at 3.6V then an approximation of its stored energy is just the product (V x I x Time = energy) so 36 Wh in this case. If you put a DC-DC converter on the output to get 5V, it's not going to deliver more energy than this: accounting for 90% efficiency, from the 36 Wh stored in the battery pack, you can expect to get 90% x 36 = 32.4 Wh on the 5V output of the DC/DC converter, or 6.5 Ah at 5V. This latter number is what is relevant from the user's point of view, as you will use the 5V output, not tap directly into the battery.
Therefore, temptation is high for powerbank manufacturers to quote the higher battery pack mAh rating instead of the lower mAh rating on the 5V output! This has become so common than the commercial mAh rating of power banks is pretty much always the sum of all cells, no matter how they're wired or what kind of DC-DC converter is used.
Honest manufacturers will quote Watt hours instead, because a Watt is a Watt no matter the voltage. If your fully charged USB-C powerbank stores 30 Wh, and your cellphone battery stores 10 Wh, you know you'll get a bit less than three full charges without having to care about voltage or marketing-enhanced mAh ratings.
Units cheat sheet:

Power P (Watts) = V (Volts) x I (Amps)
Power x time = Energy (Watt x hours or Wh)
Current x time = Capacity (Amps x hours or Ah)
Capacity x Voltage = Amps x Volts x hours = Energy (Wh)


Really, the mAh rating of power banks ought to be the current at nominal output voltage after the (usually) boost converter, but when marketing sees an excuse to put a higher number on a thing...

Sure, but bigger numbers sell more! Remember PMPO watts?

It took me a moment to realise your "special case" was sarcasm. It's late here.

What I'd add: usable capacity is often not equal to theoretical capacity. How you connect your batteries will be dictated by your voltage requirements. If end voltage is lower than your circuit can manage, the remaining capacitance won't be used. It's not too important with lithium, as the voltage is already quite high, but with AA batteries, for example it's a huge difference how low you can go, voltage-wise.

Comment only (non moderator hat) - Power banks:  Your special case is presumably sarcasm but that might possibly be made clearer given the op's technical level.

@RussellMcMahon I have added a bit more info.

I’m new here; I only read the latest revision of this answer. Even so, I was confused by the ‘special case’ paragraph (I have seen enough posts about electronics, which are hardly my area of expertise, that I expect to be confused) and did not realise it was sarcasm until I read the comments. Other users may have English as a second language or other barriers to understanding; they might be even more confused than I was! I suggest further rewriting to clarify from the start that the ‘commercial mAh rating’ used for marketing purposes is not a ‘real’ rating.

@BrianDrake Is it clearer now?

@bobflux thanks. That's starting to look like something that I wrote :-) (I tend to add a lot more detail than some people :-)) Useful for newcomers.

Alright! Thanks!

@bobflux Yes, the wording looks much better now. On principle, I don’t upvote posts outside my area of expertise, but it looks deserving of its upvotes. The reasoning seems valid and consistent with an article from a consumer organisation that I read a while ago, which claimed that the real capacity of powerbanks in their tests is usually much less than the advertised capacity (expressed in mA h).

Yeah, never buy a powerbank without finding a capacity test first, they're almost all inflated

When you connect batteries in parallel the mAh ratings add but the voltage is unchanged - each battery contributes to the total output currrent.
When you connect batteries in series the output voltage is the sum of the individual batteries, but the mAh rating is the rating of one battery - the load current has to flow through all the batteries and each battery contributes to the output voltage.
The mAh rating of a battery is only a partial measure of the energy contained in the battery - it doesn't consider battery voltage.

For most batteries, the data sheet tells you under which conditions the nominal rated capacity is defined, including voltages when the battery is considered full and empty, and the rate of discharge.

Batteries store energy, which is measured in watt-hours (Wh). For a battery, Wh can be calculated as the Battery Nominal Voltage multiplied by the Ampere Hours (Ah). For instance, multiplying 3.5 volts by 2.7 Ah equals 9.45 Wh. Thus, power accumulates. With four batteries, the total capacity is 19.8 Wh. Whether the batteries are wired in series, which sums the voltage, or in parallel, which sums the Ah, remains true.
Either way, you get 19.84 Wh
\$
19.8 Wh = 14 volts \times 2.7 Ah
\$
or
\$
19.8 Wh = 3.5 volts \times 10.8 Ah
\$
Understanding the battery's watt-hour (Wh) capacity simplifies the calculation of run times. The formula is: Hours = Wh divided by W (watts).

Wired in series, the Ah to use is the value of the weakest cell. If you try to draw more, you damage that cell.
